# Netbeans - Hide warnings during diff

Tags: netbeans, diff

I'm starting to use Netbeans (PHP) 8.0.2 for regular web projects (php/js/css).
Is there a way to avoid having the diff sidebar polluted by all the warnings ?

While those warnings are a rather good thing to notice, they are not of any use during a diff, and can make the real differences hard to notice.
(in this attached capture, only 1 change out of 7 is visible in the bar !)
[image]

My searches gave me a way to disable warnings in *tools->options->editor->hints->[choose language]*, but it also removes their display in other views, which of course is not the best way to help improving the codebase, or notice mistakes.

I also discovered a simple hack to silent a precise warning in this thread : [How to supress a warning in PHP files for Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357589/how-to-supress-a-warning-in-php-files-for-netbeans), but it's not what I need either, since I can't rewrite the whole code, especially with such an arguable and specific hack.

I'm new to Netbeans, and the diff I had in Eclipse seemed way better (at least, on the first glance).
A configuration setting, or even a plug-in to improve that would be much appreciated !

Comment: I googled this issue looking for the same answer when I came across your post. I agree, I don't see the benefit or purpose of having the warnings/hints displayed in the diff view. It clutters the display in this context, would be nice to be able to turn it off (only in diff view)

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to disable the warnings on the side since diffs are shown in the center and highlighted on both sides.

[image: Screenshot of actual diff]

Comment: After checking the interface again, I'm still surprised.
I just discovered the enum of the changes in the middle (3/7 in my capture, 1/1 on yours), and two yellow arrows **above versions list** to navigate between changes, but this seems very limited to me, and the functionnality isn't the one I was expecting : those arrows navigate between changes **among different versions**, which looks confusing to me.

Comment: For a quick comparison, Eclipse had several buttons to navigate among changes between two files (and exclusively those two files) : copy all non conflicting changes from right to left or left to right, go to previous or next diff, and so on.
I guess I also gotta check keyboard shortcuts, but this really surprises me.  Is it due to a different conception (e.g. Eclipse would be SVN-oriented, while NB would rather favor Git or Mercurial Philosophy ?)  I only know SVN.

Comment: Once you've scrolled down to a specific diff, of course it's highlighted and obvious, but I think the question is referring to the right sidebar where you see a high level overview of where the diffs in the file are, so that you can scroll or navigate to them quickly. On the right sidebar, this diff marker looks the same as the the warnings, except a different color. It would just be a little clearer if only the diff markers were displayed.