# Leaking this in constructor

Tags: java, memory-management, observer-pattern, observable

The `Controller` class is a singleton, which seems to be a special case allowing for safely passing `this` to `Controller`.

Netbeans gives

> Configure "passing suspicious parameters in the constructor" hint

for `controller.addObserver(this);` which makes me ask what the better technique would be, although I [gather it's not a good approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851843/262852).

```
package net.bounceme.dur.usenet.swing;

import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.swing.ListModel;
import net.bounceme.dur.usenet.controller.Controller;
import net.bounceme.dur.usenet.controller.MessageBean;
import net.bounceme.dur.usenet.controller.MessagesDefaultListModel;

public class MessageSelect extends javax.swing.JPanel implements Observer {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MessageSelect.class.getName());
    private Controller controller = Controller.getInstance();
    private ListModel messages = new MessagesDefaultListModel();
    private MessageBean messageBean = new MessageBean();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MessageSelect() {
        controller.addObserver(this);
        initComponents();
        messagesJList.setPrototypeCellValue("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing `this` to an external class (`Controller`) when the object hasn't been fully constructed. `Controller` could then reference your object while its construction hasn't finished.

Most people work around this by using a factory method which creates the object first, then passes `this` externally.

```
// private to force clients to use the static factory method
private MessageSelect() {
  initComponents();
  messagesJList.setPrototypeCellValue("xxx");
}

public static MessageSelect createInstance() {
  MessageSelect instance = new MessageSelect();
  instance.controller.addObserver(instance);
  return instance;
}
```

Take a look at [this excellent Brian Goetz article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html) on safe object construction.

Answer (score 1):

> Using this as parameter can be dangerous in the contructor because the object is not fully initialized

As from http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_Hints

I guess the point is, the super class may try and access apart of the class which has not yet been intialised (or you later change during your own construction)