# Is it bad practice to use ActionListener(this)

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

In a comment reply to one of my answers, [Hovercraft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) said

> No, your suggestion will make things worse really, since by using this as the ActionListener, you're suggesting that he make his View also a Control, something that shouldn't be done in anything other than "toy" programs.

As a newbie, I have always been using 'this' and I am unclear as to why this is so discouraged. Could someone could explain/elaborate Hovercraft's answer or give another?

Comment--
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021509/how-can-i-call-method-with-a-string/18021674#18021674

Comment: Instead of linking to the user can you link to the post or comment in question? Also perhaps you should try commenting to him first.

Comment: It sounds like he is advising seperation of concerns, and not make your class deal with more than it has to

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought more people would want to know too, that's why I asked

Comment: `this` in constructors: http://nat.truemesh.com/archives/000222.html can be bad.

Comment: This is in reference to the MVC design philosophy.  You can read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: If your application requires that you add action listeners to several of your components, then you also end up with a big chain of if statements trying to determine which component was the source of the event. An alternative is to use an anonymous inner class, and invoke another, more specific method (like what was probably done in the OP's post you're referring to).

Comment: Please have a look at this [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nfyly2anqmo7v87/Skeleton.java), [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cso39hh1efpcls/Skeleton1.java), [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dhwdbfxmcvpsng/Skeleton2.java) and this [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/671hqa629pbi95u/Skeleton3.java), every option has its own pros and cons associated with itself, it depends on the situation, which one is beneficial in the given senario.

Comment: Hope this link, [A Generic MVC Model in Java](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/07/07/genericmvc.html), will help you understand another way of achieving the same thingy, with a nice example :-) I wanted to put this as an answer, but I think this will make my answer too huge.

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11662858/230513) about leaking `this` from a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's cause Swing follows `MVC` pattern. If you delegate the `Controller` and `View` to one class then something wrong. Also read about [Single Responsability Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html) , a class only should be responsible to one thing , if not it's seems that your class is like a `God` that do everything.

Instead of

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
     MyJFrame(){
       this.addKeyListener(this); // sounds awful           
     }
}
```

Use something like this:

```
public class MyFrameView {

private JFrame frame;

     MyFrameView(){
       frame = new JFrame();
       frame.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
     }

}

public class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener{

}
```