# Creating a new object of class in a class

Tags: java, android, class

How do I actually create and start a new class in a class?

For example, I've got 2 class. AppsUtil.java and TTSClass.java.

From my MainActivity, I called

`new AppsUtil(MainActivity.this)`

In AppsUtil.class

```
public AppsUtil(Context context) {
    this.c = context;
    ttsInstance = new TTSClass(c);
}
```

As you can see, my AppsUtil.java created a new object of TTSClass.

```
public TTSClass(Context context) {
    this.c = context;
    this.mTts = new TextToSpeech(c, TTSClass.this);
}
```

There is no problem with this, with no logcat error or message when used.
However, TTS service doesn't speak when called.

Is there any problems with this?

EDIT:

TTSClass

```
public class TTSClass implements OnInitListener {
    String TAG = "TTSClass";
    Context c;
    TextToSpeech mTts;
    boolean ttsInitialise = false;

    public TTSClass(Context context) {
        this.c = context;
    }

    public void create() {
        Log.e(TAG, "New TTS Created");
        this.mTts = new TextToSpeech(c, TTSClass.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            // Set preferred language to US english.
            // Note that a language may not be available, and the result will
            // indicate this.
            Log.e("SUCCESS", "SUCCESS");
            int result = this.mTts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                // Lanuage data is missing or the language is not supported.
                Log.e("404", "Language is not available.");
            }
            Log.e("SUCCESS", "SUPPORTED LETS GO");
            ttsInitialise = true;
        } else {
            // Initialization failed.
            Log.e("404", "Could not initialize TextToSpeech.");
            // May be its not installed so we prompt it to be installed
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent
                    .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            c.startActivity(installIntent);
        }

    }

    public void speak(String textToSpeak) {
        if (this.mTts == null || !ttsInitialise) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LOL NO");
            return;
        }
        this.mTts.speak(textToSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problems probably lie in how you are using `mTts`, not in how you are instantiating it. Please post your code showing how you using `mTts`. You might also consider adjusting your question title and tags to be more specific to TTS as opposed to something generic to Java.

Comment: Also, probably not the issue, but passing a reference of `this` in a constructor `this.mTts = new TextToSpeech(c, **TTSClass.this**)` is an unsafe practice (`this` may not be properly initialized until after the constructor returns)

Comment: I've added TTSClass.java into the question. However I'm just worry about the context passed in is wrong. In my MainActivity, I can speak any text without any problem. Only in AppsUtil, I can't speak because TTS is not initialised.

@SJuan76 Sorry, but what do you mean?

Comment: It is called "constructor leaking" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851813/java-leaking-this-in-constructor

Comment: After reading the article and some related ones, I still don't get the issue. How do I exactly solve my problem? Is it due to the "leak constructor"? Sorry for my ignorance. Please advise. Thanks.