# How to point in a method to the object you're calling the method from? (java)

Tags: java

I am creating a method for an object in java, but I would like to use the object I'm in as parameter. So for example:

```
public void method1(String name)
{
     example = new object2(name, object1);
}
```

Where object1 should be the object I'm calling the method from. So I want to create a new object of another class, and this class will use this object as parameter.

I tried to find if there's already a question about this, but couldn't find it. I read other questions (~10) to see if they contained what I needed, but they didn't. If anyone does find a duplicate, would he / she be kind enough to also explain what search they used?

Comment: Object can be used as parameters as primitive types, there is nothing special to it.

Comment: Also noteworthy: [Is passing 'this' in a method call accepted practice in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441871/is-passing-this-in-a-method-call-accepted-practice-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, the object you are in (the one found before the dot of the method call), is referenced by the keyword `this`. So, your example would become:

```
public void method1(String name)
{
     example = new object2(name, this);
}
```

Then if you call `myObject.method1("Peter")`, the `myObject` from the calling place becomes `this` inside your method.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords), probably, will help question owner.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good pattern under the theme of your question. It's a Decorator pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern.