# Flipping game pieces in Reversi in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, reversi

I cannot get my game to correctly flip the tiles. I have been stuck on this for countless hours and can't seem to figure this out. I have checked other Reversi code examples and unfortunately still no dice. I noticed that whenever I clicked on an occupied BoardPiece in the gui, the program doesn't sense that it is occupied. Any criticism/help is encouraged! Thanks in advance.

class Index {

```
int row;
int column;

public Index(int row, int column) {
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
}

public int getRow() {
    return row;
}

public int getColumn() {
    return column;
}
public boolean equals(Index other){
    if(this.row == other.row && this.column == other.column){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

class GameBoard extends JPanel {

```
static ArrayList<BoardSquare> possibleCaptures = new ArrayList<>();
public BoardSquare BoardSquares[][] = new BoardSquare[8][8];
BoardSquare bs;
Index index;

GameBoard() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++) {
            index = new Index(row, column);
            BoardSquares[row][column] = new BoardSquare(index, Color.white);
            add(BoardSquares[row][column]);

        }
    }
}

public BoardSquare getBoardSquare(Index index) {
    return BoardSquares[index.row][index.column];
}

public void StartingPieces(HumanPlayer p1, aiPlayer p2) {

    BoardSquares[3][3].setColor(p1);

    BoardSquares[3][4].setColor(p2);

    BoardSquares[4][4].setColor(p1);

    BoardSquares[4][3].setColor(p2);

}

class BoardSquare extends JLabel {

    private Index index;
    private Color c = Color.white;
    private Border b = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2);

    BoardSquare(Index index, final Color c) {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == 1) {
                    if (c == Color.white) {
                        checkCaptures();
                        System.out.println("Checking");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("This square is already occupied.");
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        this.index = index;
        this.c = c;
        setBorder(b);

    }
    public Index getIndex(){
        return index;
    }

    public void setColor(Player p) {

        if (p instanceof HumanPlayer) {
            c = Color.blue;
        }
        if (p instanceof aiPlayer) {
            c = Color.red;
        }

    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return c;
    }

    private void checkCaptures() {
        Direction[] directions = Direction.values();

        for (Direction direction : directions) {
            // get next piece's index along the direction
            Index nextIndex = direction.next(this.index);

            if (isValid(nextIndex)) { // if the index is not valid (i.e. edge of the board) ignore it

                // get next piece in the same direction
                BoardSquare bs = getBoardSquare(nextIndex);

                // find all pieces that should be captured in this direction 
                ArrayList<BoardSquare> squaresToCapture = new ArrayList<>();
                bs.findCaptures(squaresToCapture, this.c, direction);

                for (BoardSquare candidate : squaresToCapture) {
                    // flip the color (WHITE to BLACK and vice-versa)
                    candidate.capture();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void findCaptures(ArrayList<BoardSquare> possibleCaptures, Color col, Direction d) {
        Index next = d.next(this.index);
        if (this.c == col) {
            // This piece has the same color with the first one.
            // No need to search further for this direction. All pieces collected in the list
            // between the first one and this one, have opposite color and should be captured.

        } else if (this.c == Color.white) {
            // found a blank piece. Stop the search and clear any captured pieces found so far
            possibleCaptures.clear();
        } else {
            // this piece has the opposite color of the first
            if (isValid(next)) {
                // this is not the last piece in this direction. 
                // Since it has a flipped color it is a candidate for capturing
                possibleCaptures.add(this);

                // ask the next piece recursively to also check itself
                BoardSquare bs = getBoardSquare(next);
                bs.findCaptures(possibleCaptures, col, d);
            } else {
                // next index is not valid i.e. we have reached board edge. 
                // Stop the search and clear any captured pieces found so far
                possibleCaptures.clear();
            }
        }

    }

    public void capture() {
        if (c == Color.red) {
            c = Color.blue;
        }
        if (c == Color.blue) {
            c = Color.red;
        }
    }

    public String colorStatus() {
        if (c == Color.white) {
            return "white";
        }
        if (c == Color.red) {
            return "red";
        } else {
            return "blue";
        }

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        setText(colorStatus());
    }

    public boolean isValid(Index index) {
        if (index.getRow() <= 7 && index.getRow() >= 0) {
            if (index.getColumn() <= 7 && index.getColumn() >= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have wo different variables with the same name.

```
class BoardSquare extends JLabel {

    private Index index;
    private Color c = Color.white;
    private Border b = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2);

    BoardSquare(Index index, final Color c) {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == 1) {
                    if (c == Color.white) {
```

Which `c` do you mean here? The `final Color c` or the `private Color c`? I think you *mean* `private Color c`, but you use `final Color c`.

I would suggest:

```
class BoardSquare extends JLabel {

    private Index index;
    private Color myColor = Color.white;
    private Border b = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2);

    BoardSquare(Index index, final Color initialColor) {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == 1) {
                    if (myColor.equals(Color.white)) {
```

(Not tested)

Better yet is to add the mouseListener one layer higher. (You are leaking a `this` in the constructor, which is [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851813/java-leaking-this-in-constructor))

```
for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++) {
            index = new Index(row, column);
            BoardSquares[row][column] = new BoardSquare(index, Color.white);
            BoardSquares[row][column].addMouseListener( .. );
```