# Where does 'this' refer to when creating an object of a class?

Tags: java, swing

I'm a beginner in java so sorry if the question seems a bit stupid

I have this simple code but I do not understand some of the coding.

I know that the keyword this refers to this class but i still dont understand exactly why is needed at that point .

For example :

```
public class SquareSimp
{


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        FilledFrame frame = new FilledFrame();

        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}

class FilledFrame extends JFrame
{
    int size = 400;

    public FilledFrame()
    {
        JButton butSmall   = new JButton("Small");
        JButton butMedium  = new JButton("Medium");
        JButton butLarge   = new JButton("Large");
        JButton butMessage = new JButton("Say Hi!");

        SquarePanel panel = new SquarePanel(this); WHERE DOES (THIS) REFER TO 
                                                   AND WHY DO WE NEED IT?
        JPanel butPanel = new JPanel();

        butPanel.add(butSmall);
        butPanel.add(butMedium);
        butPanel.add(butLarge);
        butPanel.add(butMessage);
        add(butPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize( size+100, size+100 );
    }

}

class SquarePanel extends JPanel
{
    FilledFrame theApp; // WHY DO WE CREATE A VARIABLE OF A TYPE CLASS? HERE?

    SquarePanel(FilledFrame app)
    {
        theApp = app;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(20, 20, theApp.size, theApp.size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to the question in itself, but considering @phflack's comment, it might be better to only pass the filled frame's size, instead of the whole object (**assuming the sample contains all of the SquarePanel's code**).

Answer (score 0):

In FilledFrame constructor we want to create an instance of SquarePanel but the thing is SquarePanel constructor requires a FilledFrame instance, so, because we already were creating FilledFrame in the first place we can send the current FilledFrame instance which is under construction as input to SquarePanel constructor.

Comment: hi, what do you mean ' because we already were creating FilledFrame in the first place' ?

Comment: We call SquarePanel constructor from FilledFrame's constructor (while we are constructing FilledFrame ).

Comment: oh ok thanks so bacisally 'this' refers to the constructor of the Squarepanel class?

Comment: No, "this" refers to the FilledFrame instance which is getting created.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE DOES (THIS) REFER AND WHY DO WE NEED IT?`

`this` represents the current instance of the class.
In this example, *JPanel*'s constructor needs an instance of the *FilledFrame* class; thus we pass that instance, which in this example is
`this` (created in the main method).

`WHY DO WE CREATE A VARIABLE OF A TYPE CLASS? HERE?`

With your design, the *SquarePanel* class depends on the *FilledFrame* class, so we have to inject a *FilledFrame* instance.
In your case, you pass it in argument to your *SquarePanel* constructor.

#### i think this is bad design anyway

Comment: Yeah, leaking the reference before the class is fully initialized can lead to some unexpected behaviour.  [java-leaking-this-in-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851843/5475891)

Comment: Please answer in proper English.

Comment: @sschrass sorry i`m new in english, can edit for me? tnx

Comment: so we pass FilledFrame to SquarePanel ?

Comment: @RANDB yes here `new SquarePanel(this)`