# Why am I getting two different outputs in Java code

Tags: java, oop, object, inner-classes

```
class A {
    int xyz = new B().show(); // prints c=0 and z=null
    int c = -319;
    B z = new B();
    int lmn = z.show(); // prints c=-319

    class B {
        int show() {
            System.out.println("c=" + c);
            System.out.println("z=" + z);
            return -555;
        }
    }
}

class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A p = new A();
    }
}
```

Why am I getting `c=0` initially and then `c=-319` later. Similarly, why is z `null` initially and after it is not `null`. What is happening in the code?

Comment: Initialization happens in order, from top to bottom. If you get rid of the `A` class and stick the logic into a method `a()`, it should be obvious what's going on.

Comment: shouldn't this statement int xyz=new B().show() give an error "Illegal forward reference" since show() uses c which has not been allocated memory yet?

Comment: Why? That's another _class_. If you could only reference classes declared in order, Java would be a very odd language indeed...

Comment: Yes it is . But it makes use of c variable of class A ,which at this stage( xyz=new B().show() ) has not been created in memory.

Comment: And that is exactly why [leaking `this` in a constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921616/java-leaking-this-in-constructor) is considered an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know that `new` operator is responsible for creating *empty* instance of class (instance with fields which will have default values: numeric:`0`; boolean:`false`, char:`'\0'`, reference:`null`). Code of constructor is invoked after `new` will finish its job, and is responsible for setting up correct state for such empty object.

Now initialization of fields happens in constructor, so your code

```
class A {
    int xyz = new B().show(); // prints c=0 and z=null
    int c = -319;
    B z = new B();
    int lmn = z.show(); // prints c=-319

    class B {
        int show() {
            System.out.println("c=" + c);
            System.out.println("z=" + z);
            return -555;
        }
    }
}
```

is is same as (notice default values)

```
class A {

    int xyz = 0;    //default values
    int c = 0;      //
    B z = null;     //
    int lmn = 0;    //

    A(){
        xyz = new B().show(); 
        c = -319;
        z = new B();
        lmn = z.show(); 
    }
    class B {
        int show() {
            System.out.println("c=" + c);
            System.out.println("z=" + z);
            return -555;
        }
    }
}
```

Also

```
xyz = new B().show();
```

is same as

```
xyz = this.new B().show();
```

so created instance of `B` will have access to instance of `A` which is initialized in current `A` constructor. BUT code which initialized `b` and `z`

```
int c = -319;
B z = new B();
```

happens after your first `show()` method (which uses `b` and `z`) which means that their default values will be shown.

This problem doesn't exist in case of second `show()`

```
lmn = z.show();
```

because now `b` and `z` are initialized.

Comment: thank you for dumping it down. Makes it so much clear. Cheers!

Comment: @user3678484 You are welcome :) BTW I added some informations which maybe will make it even clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `line 2` You are calling `int xyz = new B().show(); // prints c=0 and z=null` in the start.

Which calls

```
class B {
        int show() {
            System.out.println("c=" + c);
            System.out.println("z=" + z);
            return -555;
        }
    }
```

in above code you are accessing variable `c` and `Z` which are member variables of class and since not initialized yet they been assigned default values.

```
boolean                     =>  false
char                        =>  \u0000
int,short,byte / long       =>  0 / 0L
float /double               =>  0.0f / 0.0d
any reference type          =>  null
```

In your case `ìnt` assigned to `0` and object reference assigned to `null` :)

Move your `line 2` code to `line 4` and it should print since variable are initialized now.

Answer (score 0):

Class is instantiated with sufficient memory to contain all its' fields.

When you do:

```
A p = new A();
```

This allocates memory for A and its' fields (xyz, c, z and lmn). They are all allocated in memory with default values (c is int so 0, z is object so null [address is 0x00]).

When you run:

```
int xyz = new B().show(); // prints c=0 and z=null
```

You're creating a new instance of B. When that instance references c and z, it prints their values. Currently they are default values. For all intents and purposes, show()'s perspective is that all of the fields it references have been defined / declared, or at the very least **allocated**.

Then when you execute:

```
B z = new B();
int lmn = z.show(); // prints c=-319
```

Both c and z have gotten new values. But at all points in your code, they have been allocated and have had some value (first default).

Answer (score 0):

When you create Object of A in class C as

```
A p = new A();
```

Default construction gets class and Object gets created with class member variables with default values. At this points values of class variables are as follows:

- xyz = 0 (because it of type int)
- c = 0 (because it is also int)
- z = null (because it is reference)
- lmn = 0 (because it if of type int)

Refer below screenshot to see the variable states

[image]

When it reaches to below statement for evaluating xyz values:

```
int xyz = new B().show()
```

it prints value of c and z whose initialization is yet to done so we will get defaults values of those variables as 0 and NULL respectively.

When 2nd time, program calls show() method of class B. All variables initialization has been done because below statements are executed till the time we reaches to **z.show()**

```
int c = -319;
b z= new (B); // call the default constructor of B to create object
```

Refer to below screenshot to see the variable states.

[image]

so, it prints the value of C as -319 and z as hexadecimal values of object. (not null)