# Java construct a superclass instance with subclass instance

Tags: java

What I was trying to do is like

```
SuperClass super = convertToSuperClassInstance(SubClass sub);
```

Clearly sub could directly sign to super, But I need super should be SuperClass(remove useless subclass data), Due to other persist related things, Is there any trick I could do That?

Create new SuperClass and sign all object data to it seems no elegant to me QAQ

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36964366/8813998

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to create your own copy-constructor on the super class. Then you can do `SuperClass sup = new SuperClass(sub);`

Comment: you can cast the object to the superclass, however the overridden methods won't behave like they were of the superclass, more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21613593/11377112

Answer (score 4):

An instance of subclass will always have all the fields and methods of a superclass. Casting the subclass to superclass (i.e. `(SuperClass) subclass`) will not remove the data, it will just tell the compiler to apply the rules for SuperClass, which means you will get a compile-time error if you try to access subclass' data. Nevertheless, you can still downcast it back to subclass or use reflection - the data is there. This is by design and you can't get away from it.

If you want to really "remove" the data of a subclass, you need to construct a new instance of a superclass, not subclass. The easiest way would be to add a constructor to superclass that takes a superclass as a parameter and copies all superclass-related data from it.

Comment: This is neat and the only possible way iirc, but the overridden methods won't behave like they were of the superclass, btw +1, more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21613593/11377112