# Using 'this' in Kotlin initializer - alternative solution, or safe to ignore?

Tags: constructor, kotlin

I have a class that registers itself as an event handler, with an event service:

```
interface CommunicationService {
    fun sendActivationMessage(toEmail: String)
}

abstract class EventCommunicationService : CommunicationService, AbstractEventHandler {
    constructor(eventService: EventService) {
        eventService.registerListener(this)
    }

    override fun onEvent(event: Event) {
        if (event.type == EventType.USER_CREATED) {
            sendActivationMessage(event.userEmail)        
        }
    }
}
```

The idea being there can be an `EmailCommunicationService`, or a mocked testing version, etc. which don't all need to register themselves as listeners for when a user is created.

However Kotlin complains that I'm:

> Leaking 'this' in constructor of non-final class EventCommunicationService

Which, well, I am. I could easily ignore the warning - but is there a better approach?

**I've tried** using an `init { }` block instead of a constructor, but the warning is the same.

I basically want a "post-construct" callback or similar that can be used to let this service register itself with the EventService provided in the constructor since that's *the point* of this intermediate type.

I understand **why** this is a problem - but I'm not sure how to reason my way to fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

`init` blocks are really part of the constructor (in JVM terms), so that wouldn't help with the problem. It is very much not safe to ignore in general: see [Leaking this in constructor warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921616/leaking-this-in-constructor-warning) for reasons (just ignore the accepted answer, its comments contain the real meat and so does Ishtar's answer).

One option (assumes that all subclasses have no-argument constructors, though it could be extended):

```
abstract class <T : EventCommunicationService> EventCommunicationServiceCompanion(private val creator: () -> T) {
    operator fun invoke(eventService: EventService): T {
        val obj = creator()
        eventService.registerListener(obj)
        return obj
    }
}

// a subclass of EventCommunicationService:
class MyService private constructor () : EventCommunicationService {
    companion object : EventCommunicationServiceCompanion<MyService>(MyService::new)
}
```

To create a `MyService`, you still call `MyService(eventService)`, but this is actually the companion object's `invoke` method and not the constructor.

Comment: Do you think `lazy` initialization would be a proper solution? I think it is because we are sure that sub-classes have been initialized and a valid user of the object exists.

Comment: @AhmadRezaEnshaee Usually yes.