# How java resolve reference when use "this" key word to refer same instance before instance fully created (inside same constructor) JAVA

Tags: java, constructor

I Need some clarification how below code work in java.

I have interface call TaskDataProvider.

```
    public interface TaskDataProvider {
        String getTaskName();
    }
```

Also there is class TaskExecutor which need TaskDataProvider

```
    public class TaskExecutor {
       private TaskDataProvider taskDataProvider;

       public TaskExecutor(TaskDataProvider taskDataProvider) {
           this.taskDataProvider = taskDataProvider;
       }

       public void execute() {
           System.out.println(taskDataProvider.getTaskName());
       }
    }
```

FirstTask which crate TaskDataProvider and it contain TaskExecutor which create inside FirstTask Interface.

```
    public class FirstTask implements TaskDataProvider {

        private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

        public FirstTask() {
            this.taskExecutor = new TaskExecutor(this);
        }

        public TaskExecutor getTaskExecutor() {
            return taskExecutor;
        }

        @Override
        public String getTaskName() {
            return "First Task";
        }
    }
```

Now When we create FirstTask, we refer "this" to refer same FirstTask instance when creating TaskExecutor. 
But when the time use "this" its not fully completed FirstTask instance creation. ("this" refer inside constructor). 
I feel this flow as we are referring incomplete instance via "this"

But this is working fine. I need to know how this work fine. and it cannot be exception on any time in this process.

So please help me to understand this. 
Thanks.

Comment: the constructor is used to set a state to the instance, meaning to set a value to the instance variables, it's quite logical it already has access to them

Comment: This is exactly the [leaking `this` in a ctor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921616/leaking-this-in-constructor-warning) - so you are absolutely right - you're leaking the class before it has been fully constructed and none of the guarantees that Java provides around constructed objects yet hold - it gets worse if `FirstTask ` has a subclass...

Comment: I doubt you need to have `TaskExecutor` as an instance member of your `FirstTask`.  Very likely, any context in which you are calling `getTaskExecutor()`, you will already have a reference to that object.  And if not, I would redesign it as such.

Answer (score 2):

An object is created, before the constructor is called. Otherwise, the constructor could not access it via `this`.

You can find a quite detailed analysis of class and object instantiation here: [Java order of Initialization and Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation)

Comment: Not sure this really answers the question - the OP is asking about leaking incomplete objects, and this concern is absolutely correct.

Comment: Not an answer to the question.