# Adding Created Object to ArrayList During Initialization - Java

Tags: java, oop

in Java, I am creating a class, and I would like to keep track of all objects the are created in this class. I have implemented a way to store the names of each object (using ArrayList), but I cannot figure out how to store the object itself in the ArrayList. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    static public class Ship {
        private static ArrayList<String> ships = new ArrayList<String>();
        private static ArrayList<Ship> shipObs = new ArrayList<Ship>();
        String name;
        private ArrayList<String> cruises = new ArrayList<String>();
        int maxPassengers;
        private static final String[] CABINS = new String[] {"Balcony", "Ocean View", "Suite", "Interior"};
        private int[] passengers = new int[] {0,0,0,0};
        boolean inService = false;
        
        public Ship(String name, int maxPassengers) {
            // Ensure that each ship has a unique name
            if (ships.size() == 0) {
                this.name = name;
                ships.add(name);
            }
            else if (ships.size() >= 1) {
                for (int i=0; i < ships.size(); i++) {
                    if (ships.get(i).equals(name)) {
                        System.out.println("Ship "+name+" cannot be created because that name already exists");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                this.name = name;
                ships.add(name);
            }
            this.maxPassengers = maxPassengers;
```

As you can see, I have the static ArrayList that I would like to populate with all created ships. I assume that this population would take place in the initializing function, but the only method for doing so that I can see would to do something like

```
shipObs.add(this);
```

But that doesn't work...

Comment: what "doesn"t work mean ? You should also know that this only works for one code execution, not separate code execution `shipObs.add(this);` is the valid way

Comment: `if (ships.get(i).equals(name)) { System.out.println("Ship "+name+" cannot be created because that name already exists"); return; }` Whoa! This is in a constructor.  The object will still be created. Code like this can result in a partially constructed object.

Comment: And so you need to throw an exception if you can't create the object

Comment: Oh, I thought that it would abort the initialization... I'm VERY new to Java, so I tried to steer away from throwing Exceptions (for now) because it makes the code messy, and having to try and catch so often during testing is a drag.

Comment: You still haven't explained what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: I'm not sure why I was thinking that ```shipObs.add(this);``` wasn't working. I tested it again, and its working fine. Either way, thanks for sharing about the inaccuracy of my return statements -- I thought that if I wanted a method to throw an exception then I would have to declare that like such: ```static public class Ship throws Exception {}```

Comment: Not the class. Exceptions are thrown by *methods*.  `public Ship(String name, int maxPassengers) throws DuplicateShipException {` . Or, from my answer `public static Ship createAShip (String name, int maxPassengers) throwsDuplicateShipException {`

Comment: `shipObs.add(this);` inside the constructor can generate a "Leaking this in constructor" warning. It's not necessarily a problem. You can read more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921616/leaking-this-in-constructor-warning .

Comment: To be clear, a constructor is allowed to have `return` statements. It can even have more than one `return` statement. But, all paths to a `return` statement must result in a completely constructed `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments to the question, in addition to the problem asked about, there is another problem:  That is, the premature `return` inside the constructor. Both problems can be addressed by calling the constructor indirectly, through a `static` method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class Ship {

    // private static ArrayList<String> ships = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static ArrayList<Ship> shipObs = new ArrayList<Ship>();
    String name;
    private ArrayList<String> cruises = new ArrayList<String>();
    int maxPassengers;
    private static final String[] CABINS = 
          new String[]{"Balcony", "Ocean View", "Suite", "Interior"};
    private int[] passengers = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0};
    boolean inService = false;

    private Ship(String name, int maxPassengers) {

        this.name = name;
        // shipObs.add (this);
        this.maxPassengers = maxPassengers;
    }

    public static Ship createAShip(String name, int maxPassengers) {

        for (int i = 0; i < shipObs.size(); i++) {
            if (shipObs.get(i).name.equals(name)) {
                System.out.println("Ship " + name 
                    + " cannot be created because that name already exists");
                return shipObs.get(i);
            }
        }
        Ship theShip = new Ship(name, maxPassengers);
        ShipObs.add (theShip);
        return theShip;
    }
}
```

I made the constructor `private`. This prevents client code (code that uses the class) from calling the constructor, forcing use of the `static` method. But, this disables inheritance. To make it clear that inheritance is not allowed, I  added `final` to `public class Ship`.

As stated in the comments to the question, a constructor should not `return` before  construction of the Object is complete. If a constructor discovers it cannot be completed, an `Exception` needs to be thrown.

The static method first checks for a duplicate `Ship` `name`. If found, it returns the `Ship` that bears that name.  It would be a good idea to change that part of the code to throw an exception. A third option is to have it return `null`. Whatever the choice, it should be made clear to users of the class. This can be done using Javadoc.

If a duplicate name is not found, a new `Ship` is created and returned.

I also simplified the code that checks for a duplicate name.  If `shipObs.size()` returns zero, the `for` loop is not executed. It is not necessary to guard by enclosing within an `if`.

I also removed `ArrayList<String> ships`. Since an Object in `shipObs` has a `name` field, `ArrayList<String> ships` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use a `return` in the constructor, that would just avoid the next parameter association, you needs to throw an error to stop the instanciation process

If you may need the full objects in a list, track them only with a `List<Ship>`

You'll the simplified `if/else` system, you can try to iterate over an empty, it doesn't matter, so just do it

```java
class Ship {
    private static List<Ship> ships = new ArrayList<>();
    String name;
    int maxPassengers;

    public Ship(String name, int maxPassengers) {
        this.name = name;
        for (Ship ship : ships) {
            System.out.println(ship + " " + ship.equals(this));
            if (ship.equals(this)) {
                String msg = "Ship " + ship.name + " cannot be created because that name already exists";
                System.out.println(msg);
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
            }
        }
        ships.add(this);
        this.maxPassengers = maxPassengers;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Ship ship = (Ship) o;
        return name.equals(ship.name);
    }
}
```

If you don't care about the full objects, just use a `List<String>`

```
private static List<String> shipNames = new ArrayList<>();
public Ship(String name, int maxPassengers) {
    for (String ship : shipNames) {
        if (ship.equals(name)) {
            String msg = "Ship " + name + " cannot be created because that name already exists";
            System.out.println(msg);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
        }
    }
    this.name = name;
    shipNames.add(name);
    this.maxPassengers = maxPassengers;
}
```

---

The following code will throw the exception at the second line

```
Ship a = new Ship("ship_1", 10);
Ship b = new Ship("ship_1", 10);
Ship c = new Ship("ship_2", 10);
```